# Passing $CATALINA_HOME to Maven build task of Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, configuration, jenkins, maven-3

I am setting up a continuous integration system currently and it works pretty well. This is how it currently looks like

```
Tomcat7 with  
|- Sonar  
|- Jenkins (latest LTS version)
|  |- Maven Build  
|     | - mvn clean install
|     | - mvn site-deploy
|     | - sonar analysis
|- Site for the Maven Build
```

This makes a working build including serving the result of `mvn site` through the tomcat.

However, pushing the site-reports to the proper location within tomcat works *only* because I hardcoded `file://path/to/tomcat/webapps/site/` in the pom.xml like

```
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>local</id>
        <name>local</name>
        <url>file://path/to/tomcat/webapps/site/</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

**Problem:**
This badly couples the maven config to the location of the tomcat on the CI server, which I think should be circumvented.

**Question 1:**
Can I somehow pass $CATALINA_HOME to the corresponding Maven task launched by jenkins?

**Question 2:**
Is there probably a better way for supplying the site-reports, preferably without installing a separate webserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this problem.

**Question 1:**
I played around a bit with the settings available to the maven jobs in jenkins and discovered that it is indeed possible to just pass `${CATALINA_HOME}` which will then be extended by Jenkins.

However, this system is installed on a Windows machine and the backslash in the path of `${CATALINA_HOME}` seem to be swallowed somewhere and therefore this doesn't do the job.

**Solution:**

- in the `sentenv.bat` of tomcat I added:

  ```
  set SITE=C:/Program Files/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/site
  ```
- in the pom the corresponding part is:

  ```
  <distributionManagement>
    <site>
      <id>local</id>  
      <name>local</name>  
      <url>file://${local.site.dir}/RIAS/</url>  
    </site>  
  </distributionManagement>
  ```
- the job in jenkins then just combines the two with:
  [image]

These "properties" are then passed to maven `-Dlocal.site.dir=<resolved expression>`

**Conclusion:**
On linux systems setting the additional ${SITE} seems to be redundant. Once the swallowing of the backslashes is gone, the same holds true for windows systems. Unfortunately I cannot tell in which place the swallowing takes place.

Moreover, this decouples the configuration of the CI system from the specification in the pom.

Any further discussion and comments and are welcome.